# Read data from a file individually and multiply the two columns in C++

Tags: c++

I have a data file "1.dat" which has 4 columns and 250 rows.

I need to read each row and process it such as to multiply two columns [col1 and col2].

Can you suggest a way to do this please?

I have to use C++.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file has delimited data, you will probably:

- use `ifstream` to open the file
- use `std::getline( ifstream, line )` to read a line. You can do this in a loop. line should be of type `std::string`
- process each line using istringstream( line ) then reading these into your element.

To store the read data you could use `vector< vector< double > >` or some kind of matrix class.

with `vector<vector<double> >`

```
ifstream ifs( filename );
std::vector< std::vector< double > > mat;
if( ifs.is_open() )
{
   std::string line;
   while( std::getline( ifs, line ) )
   {
       std::vector<double> values;
       std::istringstream iss( line );
       double val;
       while( iss >> val )
       {
          values.push_back( val );
       }
       mat.push_back( values );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks CashCow. May you tell me how to extract the data from the line[row]? I need my data read in the form of a[i][j].

Comment: @negendra - Why do you *need* the data in the form `a[i][j]`?? Your question was how to read and multiply two columns of data from a file. Your comments makes it seem more like you are asking SO to do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/
Here's a few tips on how to read a file using C++, after that you're going to need to cast a string into an integer or float depending.

Comment: Thanks Bearder. I could do that but could not read all the data individually. I want to read off each data like a[i][j].May yo suggest me the way please? Thanks.